# How to secure a service REST with spring3?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, spring-security

I just made a web service with spring 3 using MVC annotations (@Controller, @RequestMapping) and now I'm looking for a way to secure it.
Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [this video](http://archive.oredev.org/topmenu/video/java/benalexspringsecurity.4.5a2d30d411ee6ffd28880001218.html) to learn about Spring-Security. Ben Alex is the founder, so well qualified to teach it.

Disclaimer: while Spring-Security will provide some authentication and access control, it won't guarantee your system is secure!

Comment: @John link is behind a paywall now.

Comment: Thanks Tony. It's probably a bit out of date now anyway.